# ubuntu-dock settings not accessible in gnome-control-center by default

Tags: 17.10, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, xdg, gnome-control-center

I recently shifted to Ubuntu 17.10. After enabling ubuntu-dock extension from Gnome-Tweak-Tools, I found no specific settings for customizing the Ubuntu-Dock in gnome-settings or gnome-control-center.
A temporary hack i found for accessing the dock settings was changing XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP variable from terminal and then launching gnome-control-center from there.

```
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=ubuntu:GNOME gnome-control-center
```

I wanted to know if there is some permanent way to get Ubuntu-Dock-Settings in gnome-control-center

Comment: Did you upgrade from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04?

Comment: yes, but  I had upgraded to ubuntu 17.04 from 16.04 only some mins before that

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you have upgraded from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 the default GNOME session(s) will still remain for you to choose during login. On top of that the all-new GNOME session(s) customised by Ubuntu (simply named *Ubuntu* and/or *Ubuntu on Xorg*) will be added.

Ubuntu dock setting is accessible only from the GNOME session(s) customised by Ubuntu, **not** from the default GNOME session(s).

When you boot your system and get to the GDM login screen you should find a cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button. If you click on the cogwheel you should find an *Ubuntu* (and/or *Ubuntu on Xorg*) option.

Choose Ubuntu (or Ubuntu on Xorg) **instead of** GNOME (or GNOME on Xorg).

---

See this if you don't have Ubuntu Dock installed in the first place: [Dock settings missing in gnome-control-center after upgrade to Ubuntu 17.10](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967590/dock-settings-missing-in-gnome-control-center-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10)

Comment: I encountered similar issues. I upgraded from 17.04. But in my case there is no Ubuntu option in the GDM login screen. I am confused about that.

Comment: I actually upgraded first from 16.04 to 17.04, then to 17.10. Before step 1, I already had unity removed and gnome-shell installed--It may be the key that caused the non-standard consequence. It is possible that some xsession files like ubuntu:GNOME.desktop (NOT gnome.desktop itself) is missing from the present system. As a result the standard ubuntu session cannot be started via GDM, and the system can only run the 'pure' gnome desktop.

Comment: @funicorn I think you should create a new Q&A with your issue and solution. I believe your situation doesn't apply to this question as OP here *has* "Ubuntu" session(s) *along with* "GNOME" session(s). They were just confused as they got logged into a GNOME session by default. But in your case the "Ubuntu" sessions were missing altogether.

Comment: **Thank you!** This turned out to be my problem for missing dock, after neither https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141537/no-dock-in-ubuntu-18-04 nor https://askubuntu.com/questions/1128506/ubuntu-18-taskbar-ubuntu-dock-hidden were of any help.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check whether following packages are installed in your system:

> ubuntu-session, ubuntu-settings, ubuntu-gnome-default-settings,
>   ubuntu-standard

After I installed these packages and rebooted, Ubuntu login option appears in the GDM chooser. Once running with that option, gnome add the dock item to the gnome-control-center. I don't know which packages make this happen. But it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue with gnome-control-center, after doing a minimal (re-)installation of Gnome 3 on Ubuntu 17.10.

I my case the solution was to install `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`.

Comment: Not the "*same*" issue. This answer is valid for this question: https://askubuntu.com/questions/967590/dock-settings-missing-in-gnome-control-center-after-upgrade-to-ubuntu-17-10