# Ubuntu 17.10 Login screen now has choice of GNOME and Ubuntu

Tags: login, lightdm, 17.10

After upgrading from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 to Ubuntu 17.10 I now have the choice of GNOME or Ubuntu on the login screen. What is the difference between these two desktops?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have upgraded from Ubuntu GNOME 17.04 the default GNOME session(s) will still remain for you to choose during login. On top of that the all-new GNOME session(s) customised by Ubuntu (simply named "Ubuntu" and/or "Ubuntu on Xorg") will be added.

You'll be missing a few modifications made by Ubuntu if you choose GNOME instead of Ubuntu, for example

- *Ubuntu Dock* and *Ubuntu appindicators* extensions will be disabled by default in a GNOME session. You [won't be able to access Ubuntu Dock settings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967118/ubuntu-dock-settings-not-accessible-in-gnome-control-center-by-default) from *Settings* application (aka `gnome-control-center`).
- The all-new shell theme created by Ubuntu (with orange highlights and dynamic top bar transparency) [won't be loaded by default](https://askubuntu.com/questions/969657/how-to-install-the-latest-ubuntu-17-10-shell-theme-under-ubuntu-with-vanilla-gno) in a GNOME session.