# Ubuntu 18 taskbar (Ubuntu Dock) hidden

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension

I'm facing issues recently with Ubuntu 18 after deleting unused kernels by

```
sudo apt-get autoremove --purge
```

taskbar is not appearing.

[image]

Tapping <kbd>Super</kbd> shows taskbar.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure Ubuntu Dock is installed by running the following command in Terminal

```
sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
```

and then re-login.

Note that if you enable the '*Auto-hide the Dock*' option in Ubuntu Dock settings, then the dock would be hidden until mouseover to dodge windows. To make the dock visible all the time launch **Settings** application and in the '**Dock**' section disable '*Auto-hide the Dock*'.