# No Dock in Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock

I can only see default GNOME Dock when I click Activities:

[image]
[image]

What I am already trying to do:

1. I try remove GNOME files like `.gnome .gnome2 .gconf .gconfd .metacity`
2. I disable all installed Gnome Extensions with **Gnome Tweaks** GUI.
3. I 'Reset to Defaults' all **Gnome Tweaks**.
4. I reset all changes in gnome with `dconf reset -f /org/gnome/`
5. I try install `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` but get message it already installed: `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock is already the newest version (0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3).`
6. Thousands restarts and log-out's..

Comment: try this `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` logout and login to any tty and then `sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have personally experienced this many times.. as the first thing I do in lot of fresh Installations of Ubuntu 18.04 is to run `sudo rm -rf /usr/share/gnome-shell/extenisons/*` This will remove the pre-enabled extensions but apt still thinks this is not removed from the system and that's why it says `gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock is already the newest version (0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3).`

Example:

```
pratap@i7-4770U:~$ ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
ubuntu-appindicators@ubuntu.com  ubuntu-dock@ubuntu.com
pratap@i7-4770U:~$ sudo rm -rf /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/*
[sudo] password for pratap: 
pratap@i7-4770U:~$ ls /usr/share/gnome-shell/extensions/
pratap@i7-4770U:~$ sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock is already the newest version (0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
pratap@i7-4770U:~$ sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock* ubuntu-desktop*
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 2 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
After this operation, 687 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
(Reading database ... 233472 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing ubuntu-desktop (1.417.1) ...
Removing gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock (0.9.1ubuntu18.04.3) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.56.4-0ubuntu0.18.04.2) ...
pratap@i7-4770U:~$
```

so, the workaround is to purge the extension with the below command

`sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`

and then re-install with

`sudo apt install gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock`

between these two commands, I am not sure.. whether these commands are required or not

`sudo apt autoremove && sudo apt autoclean`
`gnome-session-logout`

and then Install it from any tty, I did not remember it when I came across with this situation.. but guessing is that `sudo apt purge gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock` command will remove `ubuntu-desktop` also