# Can't install "Desktop Icons" because this extension is enabled by my current mode, I can't install manually any update in this session

Tags: gnome-shell, 19.10, gnome-shell-extension, desktop-icons

In Firefox, I tried to install GNOME Shell extension  **Desktop Icons** made by Rastersoft, but I got this error:
[image: In Firefox, I am trying to install **Desktop Icons** made by Rastersoft.]

I need some icons my Desktop which include both folder & *Indicator-sticky-notes*. Installing other extensions is not the option because they will obviously lack:

1. Resize desktop icons
2. Hide Trash and Home folder

I don't want to install any other FileManager too. I am **ok** with Nautilus even though it sucks at some level.

Now, the main question is: **Is there a way to get out of this session, install this extension and go back to my previous session?** or something that solves this problem.

Comment: I am Confused, can you clarify.. 19.10 by default comes with this extension rite.. is there any difference between default one and the extension in Q? how did you come to know the difference?

Comment: Since 19.10, yes this extension comes pre-installed. I thought since this extension is disabled and I can still view all desktop icons which I need, why do I need it? So I removed it completely. @PRATAP

Comment: did you remove it manually?

Comment: @PRATAP yes I did.

Comment: Ok.. then `sudo apt install --reinstall gnome-shell-extension-desktop-icons`

Comment: a similar case.. https://askubuntu.com/q/1141537/739431

Comment: The update is, I have installed vanilla-gnome-desktop now. Should I remove/purge ubuntu-session? I waited for someone else to mention some ideas and at last, did what @pomsky suggested.

Comment: no, dont follow my thread if you already installed `vanilla-gnome-desktop`.

Comment: @PRATAP now things are messier. I have two sessions installed. Seeing some weird things like I can't remove favorite applications. It is ok to completely remove ubuntu-session?

Comment: you don't need to remove anything.. just choose which one to login.. GNOME or Ubuntu. if you logon to Ubuntu run the reinstall command and it should bring back the extension.

Comment: I just ran sudo apt remove --purge vanilla-gnome-desktop, it says ot is not installed! weird. @PRATAP And when I used sudo apt remove --purge gnome-session, it also didn't undo everything. Everything in a sense, where I don't have any option too choose.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the most convenient way for you would be installing the `vanilla-gnome-desktop` metapackage by running

```
sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop
```

After installation reboot (or logout) and choose (after clicking the cogwheel (⚙️) next to the sign in button) a 'GNOME' session (instead of 'Ubuntu') from the GDM login screen. You'll then get the vanilla GNOME session sans any modification by Ubuntu.

Comment: I want to uninstall what I installed yesterday. But uninstalling vanilla doesn't remove all meta-packages which came with it. A list is so big as u can see here: https://pastebin.com/2AGdYjtJ How can I uninstall them without affecting ubuntu-session?

Comment: Please [refer to this](https://askubuntu.com/q/1111491/480481). The safest option would be removing the packages manually making sure `ubuntu-desktop` metapackage is not removed in the process.